# How to reset form after mailto?

Tags: forms, action, reset, mailto

First question! Glad to be here. :)

I have a form set up to validate the input, and then if all fields are valid, send the entered information over to an email:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="mailto:someemail@me.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

Everything works great! But now I need to reset the form after the information is transferred to the email (because my form is hidden on the same page, user can click the button again to make the form appear and the information from last time is still there). I can't add a line to my validateForm() to reset it because that happens before the information is transferred over, causing the email to lose the entered information. I also can't force the page to reset the form onload, because my webpage isn't reloaded after submission, and I certainly don't want to have to set a timer to clear it.

So my question is, how do I reset the form after the entered information is transferred to an email, using only HTML and JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: It does require a third party solution. It requires your client to have an email program installed **on his machine**, and even that is patchy. When you use PHP (for example) to send a mail, the result is consistent throughout browsers and clients. Don't do something because it's **easy**, do it because it's **correct**. Especially if you're selling a product/service to a customer.

Comment: Oh I'm not, I'm just a student. This is for an assignment, and was told by my instructor to use mailto. I know nothing about PHP - this is my first web dev course.

Comment: Okay than, just stating it for reference :)